# How to remove the first duplicate values from a List?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In a List, how can we remove the first coming duplicate values?

Example: The list contains: `{"lst1","lst2","lst3","lst4","lst2","lst1"}`.

Expected Output like: `{"lst3","lst4","lst2","lst1"}`.

How can I do this using LINQ or any other method?

Comment: @MichaelRandall _"why does a duplicate care if its first or not if the items are exactly the same?"_ As per my understanding of the OP's question, the order of the elements matter. Removing an item from the beginning of the list produces a different result than removing the same item from the end of the list.

Comment: Please show us your attempt at this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you only want to keep the last "duplicate" values, you may use something like the following:

```
list.Where((s, i) => !list.Skip(i + 1).Contains(s))
```

**Full example:**

```
var list = new List<string> { "lst1", "lst2", "lst3", "lst4", "lst2", "lst1" };
var result = list.Where((s, i) => !list.Skip(i + 1).Contains(s)).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
```

**Output:**

```
lst3,lst4,lst2,lst1
```

---

If you really want to remove only the first duplicate items and keep the rest (if an item is duplicated more than once), you may use the following:

```
list.Where((s, i) => list.Take(i).Contains(s) || !list.Skip(i + 1).Contains(s))
```

**Demo:**

```
var list = new List<string> { "lst1", "lst2", "lst3", "lst4", "lst2", "lst1", "lst1" };
var output = list.Where((s, i) => list.Take(i).Contains(s) || 
                                  !list.Skip(i + 1).Contains(s)).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", output));
```

**Output:**

```
lst3,lst4,lst2,lst1,lst1
```